Computing the probability density of a function of non-iid random variables.
I am trying to compute the probability density of a function of some non-$iid$ random variables $X_1, X_2,$ and $X_3$ from their joint distribution $f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. In particular, I am trying to obtain the probability distribution of the random variable $X$, which is defined as $X = \frac{X_1 - X_2}{X_1 + X_2 + X_3}$.
By definition, we have $$ f_X(x) = \int \int \int f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(x_1,x_2,x_3) \delta\left(x - \frac{x_1 - x_2}{x_1 + x_2 + x_3}\right)~ dx_1 dx_2 dx_3$$
where the integral is over the entire sample space.
Let us take a special case, where $f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(x_1,x_2,x_3) = 6$ when $1>x_1>x_2>x_3>0$, and $f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(x_1,x_2,x_3) = 0$ otherwise. We see that the joint density $f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}$ is normalized. So we now need to evaluate the below integral $$ f_X(x) = 6 \int_{0}^{1} dx_1 \int_{0}^{x_1} dx_2 \int_{0}^{x_2} dx_3 ~\delta\left(x - \frac{x_1 - x_2}{x_1 + x_2 + x_3}\right).$$
I don't know how to proceed further. In particular, I am facing difficulties in evaluating the integral of the multivariate delta function. Can you help me proceed further?

Let's recall the following property of the Dirac delta function for continuously differentiable function $\phi(x)$:
$$
\delta(\phi(x)) = \sum_k \frac{\delta(x-x_k)}{|\phi'(x_k)|}
$$
where $x_k$ are the zeroes of $\phi(x)$. Now, let's define the function
$$
\phi(x_3) = x - \frac{x_1-x_2}{x_1+x_2+x_3},
$$
whose unique zero is given by
$$
x_* = -\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)x_1-\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)x_2,
$$
together with
$$
\phi'(x_*) = \frac{x^2}{x_1-x_2}.
$$
In consequence, one has :
$$
\begin{align}
f_X(x) &= \int\mathrm{d}x_1 \int\mathrm{d}x_2 \int\mathrm{d}x_3 \; f_{X_1X_2X_3}(x_1,x_2,x_3) \, \delta\left(x - \frac{x_1-x_2}{x_1+x_2+x_3}\right) \\
       &= \int\mathrm{d}x_1 \int\mathrm{d}x_2 \; \frac{f_{X_1X_2X_3}(x_1,x_2,x_*)}{|\phi'(x_*)|} \\
       &= \int\mathrm{d}x_1 \int\mathrm{d}x_2 \; \frac{|x_1-x_2|}{x^2} f_{X_1X_2X_3}\left(x_1,x_2,-\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)x_1-\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)x_2\right)
\end{align}
$$
